# Passing a Local to a Python program from Stata

Tags: python, stata, stata-macros

I am trying to write a Stata program that passes a local to a Python function. It is based on [this example](https://blog.stata.com/2023/07/25/a-stata-command-to-run-chatgpt/), where this approach works.

Here is a toy example demonstrating the problem:

```
python clear
capture program drop get_data
program get_data
     version 17
     args InputText
     python: get_data()
end

python:

from sfi import Macro

def get_data():
     inputtext = Macro.getLocal('InputText')
     print(inputtext)
     
end

local InputText "YYY"
python: get_data()

get_data "XXX"
```

The first works, the second does not:

```
. local InputText "YYY"

. python: get_data()
YYY

. 
. get_data "XXX"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'get_data' is not defined
r(7102);
```

I would like to get a fix with an explanation.

Comment: Try changing the order where Python method `get_data` is defined _before_ the Stata program.

Comment: @Parfait I tried that, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this code into a file called get_data.ado seems to do the trick:

```
python clear
capture program drop get_data
program get_data
     version 17
     args InputText
     python: get_data()
end

python:

from sfi import Macro

def get_data():
     inputtext = Macro.getLocal('InputText')
     print(inputtext)

end
```

Here is the result:

```
. get_data "XXX"
XXX
```

I would still love to understand why it has to go into a separate file.

Comment: For future readers, please provide fuller code that shows how you reference the external file.

Comment: Even in the Stata docs you link, examples use separate ado files. Only methods are defined without actual calls.

Comment: @Parfait I missed that when I asked my question. Can you elaborate on why separate files are important?